# Running Multiple Processes

Tags: vb.net, process, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

The following code I'm about to posts works fine, however I need to be able to kick off multiple processes at the same time.

So to give some background, the listbox contains files that will be run through another process to create PDF files (essentially passing arguments to the other process which is the exe listed in the `StartInfo.Filename`). What's currently happening, say the listbox contains 10 files. Each file will be processed separately before the additional files are processed. I'd like to be able to kick off all 10 files at the same time instead of waiting. Some files may take longer than others, so I'm wasting time waiting for each file to finish.

Suggestions?

```
            Dim UPSFiles = (From i In ListBoxUPSFiles.Items).ToArray()
        For Each Item In UPSFiles
            Dim UPSFiles2 = Item.ToString
            Using psinfo As New Process
                psinfo.StartInfo.FileName = "\\dgrvdp1\ClientServices\APPS\Printtrack\HeliosPNetExecuter\HeliosPNetExecuter.exe "
                psinfo.StartInfo.Arguments = Arg2 + Arg3 + Arg4 + (Chr(34) + DATA_PATH + "\" + UPSFiles2 + Chr(34) + " ") + Arg6 + Arg7 + Arg8 + Arg9a + Arg10 + Arg11 + Arg13
                psinfo.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                psinfo.Start()
                'psinfo.WaitForExit()
            End Using
        Next
```

**EDIT**
Here's my current code, based on the `Parallel.ForEach` suggestion. It appears to sort of worked but submitted 10x the number of files I need to run. In my case, I have two files to process however like I mention the code produced 10x the number of processes I truly need.

```
            Dim SequentialFiles = (From i In ListBoxSequentialFiles.Items).ToString
        For Each Item In SequentialFiles
            Dim SequentialFiles2 = Item.ToString

            Parallel.ForEach(SequentialFiles2, Sub(processFiles)

                                                   Using psinfo As New Process
                                                       psinfo.StartInfo.FileName = "\\dgrvdp1\ClientServices\APPS\Printtrack\HeliosPNetExecuter\HeliosPNetExecuter.exe "
                                                       psinfo.StartInfo.Arguments = Arg2 + Arg3 + Arg4 + (Chr(34) + DATA_PATH + "\" + SequentialFiles2 + Chr(34) + " ") + Arg6 + Arg7 + Arg8 + Arg9c + Arg10 + Arg11 + Arg12
                                                       psinfo.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
                                                       psinfo.Start()
                                                       psinfo.WaitForExit()
                                                   End Using

                                               End Sub)

        Next
```

Comment: [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)?

Comment: One way to do it is to create a backgroundworker to process each item, or use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.  Either way will create a new thread to process each item.

Comment: @crashmstr I must've failed miserably at the attempt to use your suggestion. It appeared to work, however the code I'll post produced 10x the number of files I submitted, in my case I have two files to run at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how is PDF processor work. You can avoid creting threads, but simply launch 10 processes, by feeding inside one file per process. No need of multi threading, at this stage at least.

Comment: I thought the For Each would do that, feeding one file at time. Right now, it waits until the first file is processed before kicking off any remaining processes. I'm just having a hard time kicking off multiple processes based on items in my listbox.

Comment: Yes, you can run all processes, and collect them in collection. After handle thier completeion separately. My point is, you don't need `Parallel.ForEach`, *for that*.

Comment: Suggestions on how to collect the processes? As I said, my current For Each statement I thought would've handled this, looping through each file in the listbox and kicking off the process.

Comment: Just launch processes one after another and *instances* , subscribe to events of every single process. Once arbitrary process will completed, it will raise an event, you will handle it and do something appropriate.